# Question on Expectation Fact

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $X$ be a non-necessarily stochastically independent random variable with values in $\mathbb N_0$ = {$0,1,2,...$} and E[$X^2$]$< \infty$.

Is the following statement always true or false ?

E[$\sqrt{X}$]$< \infty$

I am not too sure. I am thinking it's false but can't find a counterexample.

Comment: For integers $n\ge0$ one always has $\sqrt n < n^2$, so...

Comment: So you are saying that E$[\sqrt(X)] < E[X^2]$ is always true ? But I guess something like $E[X^2] \leq E[X]^2$ is not always true ?

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{1/2}>(1/2)^2$, so the inequality $E[\sqrt X]\le E[X^2]$ doesn't hold for general $X\ge0$ rvs.  But it does for integer ones.

Comment: @kimchilover Okay so your first reply is a good way of thinking about these questions right ?. Thanks. So to confirm, the statement must be true.

Comment: @kimchilover Question. If random variable $X$ is independent, that doesn't imply that $X^2$ or $\sqrt{X}$ is independent ? But it does imply that $\sin(X)$ is independent and that $e^X$ is independent ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a random variable being "independent".  The term always describes the relationship between 2 or more random variables, as in "$X$ is independent of $Y$", or in "$X,Y$, and $Z$ are not independent", etc.

Comment: @kimchilover The same meaning as the one at the beginning of the question in my opening post when it says $X$ is non-necessarily stochastically independent random variable

Comment: @NikitaMazepin the question applies to that too: it does not seem meanningful  for a single random variable